# Bootstrap nav logo pushes navigation down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Relavent page here: http://marcmurray.net/test_sites/cans/#

Basically I have added an svg image into my navbar into the navbar-brand class, but it has pushed all of my navigation down and outside of itself, can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-left"><img src="img/logo.svg"></a>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php" class="activepage">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="why.php">Why Us?</a></li>
                <li><a href="process.php">Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: now it looks better) did your find what you loking for?

Comment: Hi! Yeah I made a dumb mistake, then stuck img-responsive onto it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="img/logo.svg"></a></div>
```

You have a missing div closure there

Answer (score 0):

You missing `navbar-header` closing `</div>` after logo:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    ...
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-left"><img src="img/logo.svg"></a>
</div> - add this
```

Answer (score 0):

Three opened divs but two closed divs. 
Check it!